# Query timeout in embedded RDLC vb 2008

Tags: vb.net

How does one increase the query timeout when using local reportviewer from the default of 30 seconds.
I am not using code to create the dataset. I went through wizard choosing connection and setting the report to use a stored procedure to fill adapter.
I don't have access to change ds.querytimeout setting.
This is a not using SSRS. the report is local and embedded.
call the report as such

```
                ReportForm2.SpRetrieveReportIncentiveSummaryTableAdapter.Fill(ReportForm2.Prdatalyons728DataSet.spRetrieveReportIncentiveSummary, tStart.Text, tEnd.Text, areas, pickers, " ", "hh:mm:ss", 0, " ")
            ReportForm2.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add it like this
 ReportForm.SpRetrieveReportIncentiveSummaryTableAdapter1.SetCommandTimeOut=

Set the timeout on the table adapter